# How to load cloth baked cache?

Tags: baking, cloth-simulation, cache

I am new to blender.

Created a character, made cloth pants and shirt to the character, baked the simulation to the disk (a folder was created at the same folder with the project called blendcache_ProjectName with all the baked files in it)

But as soon as i restart the blender and load this project, all the clothes are at the initial state and i can't find any way to load the baked cache, so i don't have to simulate it again. Apparently blender see these files according to the screenshot, but whenever i start the playback, they're static.

Anything i miss?
Thanks.

[image: Cache screenshot]